# Recomendation of Ruby on Rails hosting

Tags: web-hosting, ruby-on-rails

> **Duplicate:**
>   [Web hosting options for Ruby on Rails applications](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8129/web-hosting-options-for-ruby-on-rails-applications)

Hi,

We're looking for a good Ruby on Rails hosting. Basically we need the following features:

- Unlimited disk space and monthly bandwidth
- Unlimited domains
- Full SSH access
- Support various versions of Rails (2.3.8 and 3.0 for ex.)
- Passenger and capistrano deployment support
- EXCELLENT client support: We're new at Ruby on Rails, so currently we have several problems when deploying rails app. Our current hosting (RailsPlayground) offers awesome support, but we are looking for a new one because of the disk space and bandwidth limits.
- A nice panel (cPanel or similar).
- Basically we need to focus on application development and not worry too much about deployment and related stuff.
- Fair price

We need a truly Ruby on Rails hosting, with people that have expertise in deploying and hosting Rails apps., not just a normal hosting that someday decided to install ruby and rails just to support it, if you know what I mean.

We don't need high performance, we need to host several rails applications. If one application is getting lots of traffic and needs better performance, then we'll move it to a VPS or some high-scalable and performance hosting.

I'll create some answers with a few hostings that I've been recommended. Please feel free to vote and add comments about them or reply with another.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest contributing to [this listing](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8129/web-hosting-options-for-ruby-on-rails-applications) over at webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh ok, I had the feeling this was not the right place to post this. Thanks. Vote for close it

Answer (score 1):

[DreamHost](http://www.dreamhost.com)

Answer (score 1):

[BlueHost](http://www.bluehost.com)

Answer (score 1):

[HostGator](http://www.hostgator.com)