# Where can I host / run periodically a ruby script for free?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Web hosting options for Ruby on Rails applications](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8129/web-hosting-options-for-ruby-on-rails-applications)

I need a ruby script I wrote to run periodically (everyday) but I dont want to run it on my computer, depending on it being on, etc...

Does anyone know of a free, or very cheap, hosting service that would allow me to do this? I dont need to host any front end or anything, just the script.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your requirements are, [Heroku](http://heroku.com) is free. You would need to run the code in the context of a rails app though. Looks like [daily cron](http://addons.heroku.com/cron) is free.

Comment: So do you think I could just install a barebones Rails app in Heroku, put the script on there and configure cron to run it? Is it not possible to upload standalone files to heroku?

Comment: Yes, you can install a bare bones rails app and have cron run Ruby code daily that you upload to Heroku. Here is the documentation for setting up a cron job on Heroku: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cron