# Hosting for a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Web hosting options for Ruby on Rails applications](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8129/web-hosting-options-for-ruby-on-rails-applications)

I am a Ruby on Rails developer and I am planning to purchase an hosting space in order to publish my web application (I'm developing a small Social Network). This is my first time that I try to deploy a Ruby on Rails application, so I am not expert on the matter.

I would like to find a "compromise" between performance and price. I think that for now a shared server it is enough (maybe) for my needs (suggestions are appreciated...).

In localhost I am using

- Ruby on Rails 3.0.9
- ruby-1.9.2-p136
- Apache
- Phusion Passenger
- MySql

so the hosting server should satisfy the above requisites.

More: in my application I am using the Paperclip gem so another requisite should be Image-Magick.

What hosting service do you advice for my needs? What should I have to care when I purchase a hosting space for RoR? And, most importantly, which hosting service do you advice?

P.S.: if you need some other information just ask and I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest trying [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) out. Once you have it going you'll get a better understanding of what you need and will move to dedicated hosting if needed.